# Pushing Cloudwatch Logs from Linux Instance - RequestError: Server Misbehaving

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, http-proxy

I am trying to push logs to Cloudwatch from a RHEL Instance. Originally I was getting the error:

`[outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Aws error received when sending logs to LogGroup/LogStream: RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://logs.<region>.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:443: i/o timeout`

I tried everything I could think of, I saw some things online that it could be Proxy related. I have a proxy server instance on the AWS account.
I added the following into the common-config.toml for Cloudwatch:

`[proxy] http_proxy = "htttp://${PROXY_SERVER}:$PORT" https_proxy = "http://${PROXY_SERVER}:$PORT" no_proxy = "XX.XX.XX.XX"`

The error I am getting now is:
`[outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Aws error received when sending logs to LogGroup/LogStream: RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://logs.<region>.amazonaws.com/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http on XX.XX.XX.XX:53: server misbehaving`

I am in a private VPC and I can't ping public sites as I get 100% packet loss. I can manually run the AWS Cli command to push an entry into the log stream. For now I am just trying to push /var/log/messages from my instance. Can anyone help with why the CloudWatch logs aren't pushing?

Some thing I have tried that didn't work for the original error:

- exporting no_proxy
- adding AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS as an env variable
- Ensuring port 443 is open on SG's
- Ensuring IAM profile has correct permissions for CW and EC2

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure this out? If not, if your EC2 instance is within the VPC, perform the following:

1/ Create a security group named `tls-within-vpc` that allows inbound and output traffic only on port 443 to your VPC CIDR block, and attach that security group to your EC2 instance.

2/ Create VPC endpoints each for `monitoring` and `logs` AWS services in your region. Attach the `tls-within-vpc` security group you created above to the VPC endpoints you created

3/ Restart cloudwatch agent in your EC2 instance.

As long as there's no syntax errors in your cloudwatch agent configuration json file, that should fix your problem. Let me know if you're still having issues with that.

With this setup, you do not need to set `no_proxy` or set `AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS`.